# Two queries to the same table

Tags: peewee

I need to get 25 rows from a table.
First I need to get all pinned threads. Then I need to get (25 - pinned) regular threads.

Is it possible at all to get these rows using one query?
Now I use two separate queries like this:

```
p = Thread.select().where(Thread.pinned).limit(25)
t = Thread.select().where(Thread.pinned >> None).limit(25-len(p))
```

Comment: What type of field is pinned? Can you show us the relevant parts of your Model definition?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you could do:

```
case_stmt = case(None, (
  (Thread.pinned >> None, 0),
), 1))
(Thread
 .select(Thread, case_stmt.alias('pinned_first'))
 .order_by(SQL('pinned_first').asc())
 .limit(25))
```